How can I anonymously pull from gcr.io in kaniko in Gitlab?
As part of a kaniko build in Gitlab I am using a container hosted on gcr.io It seems anonymous login is denied.
This requires me to obtain a short-term credential for my account.
I would like

my build to function without this.
not to have to set up a service account

I have injected configuration into /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$GCR_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$GCR_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$GCR_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - more /kaniko/.docker/config.json

this works and uses

a user id of oauth2accesstoken
a password created by gcloud auth print-access-indentity

based on https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token
I am also aware that a Gitlab is authenticated with GCR, as
gcloud auth print-access-indentity and gcloud auth print-indentity-token
when calling inside a container with gcloud installed and no prior authorisation.
However, I have not found a way to use these credentials.
